# Puts arrays in file using ruby

Tags: ruby, file

This is a part of my file:

```
project(':facebook-android-sdk-3-6-0').projectDir = new File('facebook-android-sdk-3-6-0/facebook-android-sdk-3.6.0/facebook')
project(':Forecast-master').projectDir = new File('forecast-master/Forecast-master/Forecast')
project(':headerListView').projectDir = new File('headerlistview/headerListView')
project(':library-sliding-menu').projectDir = new File('library-sliding-menu/library-sliding-menu')
```

I need to extract the names of the libs. This is my ruby function:

```
def GetArray
  out_file = File.new("./out.txt", "w")
  File.foreach("./file.txt") do |line|
    l=line.scan(/project\(\'\:(.*)\'\).projectDir/)
    File.open(out_file, "w")  do |f|
      l.each do |ch|
        f.write("#{ch}\n")
      end
    end
    puts "#{l} "
  end
end
```

My function returns this:

```
[] 
[["CoverFlowLibrary"]] 
[["Android-RSS-Reader-Library-master"]] 
[["library"]] 
[["facebook-android-sdk-3-6-0"]] 
[["Forecast-master"]]
```

My problem is that I find nothing in `out_file`. How can I write to a file? Otherwise, I only need to get the name of the libs in the file.

Comment: no solution to this ?

Comment: Why do you call `File.new` and then `File.open`? They do the same thing.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "no solution to this?" Um... really? You created the question at 12:17 and expected an answer by 12:41? Understand that SO is a voluntary-help site, where people pick and choose what questions they want to work on. We're not on anyone's schedule, and answers could come from anywhere on earth. You could get answers days, weeks or months later, as people get to them. Also, your input data doesn't match the returned data as there are things not in the input. It's essential your input and output make sense.

Comment: Hi bro thank's for your special response, I did it because I found some gentelmen gives me -1 vote or they edit some capital letter.

What I need is a solution or an idea near to solution.

Have a nice day

Comment: thank's @EugZol it was my error, File.open and File.new are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meditate on this:

```
"project(':facebook-android-sdk-3-6-0').projectDir'".scan(/project\(\'\:(.*)\'\).projectDir/)
# => [["facebook-android-sdk-3-6-0"]]
```

- When [`scan`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/String.html#method-i-scan) sees the capturing `(...)`, it will create a sub-array. That's not what you want. The knee-jerk reaction is to `flatten` the resulting array of arrays but that's really just a band-aid on the code because you chose the wrong method.

Instead consider this:

```
"project(':facebook-android-sdk-3-6-0').projectDir'"[/':([^']+)'/, 1]
# => "facebook-android-sdk-3-6-0"
```

This is using String's [`[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) method to apply a regular expression with a capture and return that captured text. No sub-arrays are created.

`scan` is powerful and definitely has its place, but not for this sort of "find one thing" parsing.

Regarding your code, I'd do something like this untested code:

```
def get_array
  File.new('./out.txt', 'w') do |out_file|
    File.foreach('./file.txt') do |line|
      l = line[/':([^']+)'/, 1]
      out_file.puts l
      puts l
    end
  end
end
```

- Methods in Ruby are *NOT* camelCase, they're snake_case. Constants, like classes, start with a capital letter and are CamelCase. Don't go all Java on us, especially if you want to write code for a living. So `GetArray` should be `get_array`. Also, don't start methods with "get_", and don't call it `array`; Use `to_a` to be idiomatic.
- When building a regular expression start simple and do your best to keep it simple. It's a maintainability thing and helps to reduce insanity. `/':([^']+)'/` is a lot easier to read and understand, and accomplishes the same as your much-too-complex pattern. Regular expression engines are greedy and lazy and want to do as little work as possible, which is sometimes totally evil, but once you understand what they're doing it's possible to write very small/succinct patterns to accomplish big things.

  Breaking it down, it basically says "find the first `':` then start capturing text until the next `'`, which is what you're looking for. `project(` can be ignored as can `).projectDir`.

And actually,

```
 /':([^']+)'/
```

could really be written

```
/:([^']+)'/
```

but I felt generous and looked for the leading `'` too.

Comment: Thank's for you explication, you're the best.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're opening the file twice: once in:

```
  out_file = File.new("./out.txt", "w")
```

and then once for each line:

```
    File.open(out_file, "w")  do |f| ...
```

Try this instead:

```
def GetArray
  File.open("./out.txt", "w") do |f|
    File.foreach("./file.txt") do |line|
      l=line.scan(/project\(\'\:(.*)\'\).projectDir/)
      l.each do |ch|
        f.write("#{ch}\n")
      end  # l.each
    end    # File.foreach
  end      # File.open
end        # def GetArray
```